# What does cross platform mobile app development mean? In simple terms

Tags: android, iphone, mobile, cross-platform, mobile-application

I need to know What does cross platform mobile app development mean? 
In simple terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an ideal world, it means "write once, run on many platforms". There are many tools to write once code base and compile apps to run on Android, iOS, BB10, etc... While they are great tools, each has some limitations, but it's worth researching them.

Some examples are:

- [CoronaSDK](http://coronalabs.com)
- [Marmalade](http://madewithmarmalade.com)
- [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com)
- [Unity](http://unity3d.com)
- [CodenameOne](http://codenamenone.com)
- [Gingee](http://gingeegames.com) - this one is new
- ...

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do it (i guess) is develop a html5 app to work with IOS, Windows Phone a Android Device.

u can develop for example a WebApp for each plataform (i will talk about only three top, IOS, ANDROID and Windows Phone). But u will need that your HTML5 works for each webapp render engine.

Answer (score 1):

There are various Mobile Application Development Platforms available such as PhoneGap, Kony or JQueryMobile which allows you to develop in a single language and run on multiple platforms. The big problem with these is that you usually lose some native look and feel.

Answer (score 1):

It means a way to develop apps for different platforms, like Android, iOS and Blackberry with the same source code. Normally you would have to develop each app separately using it's own development kit, depending on the platform.
An example of a framework that allows you to do cross-platform development is [Phonegap](http://phonegap.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Cross-platform mobile development means you can develop apps for the different platform. let me give you an example take a Saas based application development platform [Wavemaker](http://www.wavemaker.com). Build your app using [WaveMaker](http://www.wavemaker.com) and launch it in one go both on Andriod and IOS with the same source code.

Answer (score 0):

Cross-platform mobile development refers to the development of mobile apps that can be used on multiple mobile platforms.

In the business world, a growing trend called BYOD (Bring Your Own Device) is rising. BYOD refers to employees bringing their own personal mobile device into the workplace to be used in place of traditional desktop computers or company-provided mobile devices for accessing company applications and data. Because of BYOD, it has become necessary for businesses to develop their corporate mobile apps and be able to send them to many different mobile devices that operate on various networks and use different operating systems.

Following technologies are used for developing cross platform apps.

phonegap

titanium

sencha touch

xamarin etc...